# Angular 2 provider instance on logout

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to Angular 2/Ionic 2 and I have one problem with logout functionality in Ionic 3.
I created a common service to store and use some app constants through out the app.
E.g i want to store http header info and share it in all providers.

userId,vendorId details are from database.i am setting that in login method.

```
this.headers = new Headers({
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'UserId': userId,
        'VendorId': vendorId,
        'RoleId': roleId
    });
```

I am injecting this common service in other providers and using like this

```
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.appConstants.headers });
let body = JSON.stringify(Userinfo);
return this.http.post(this._url + 'SaveUser', body, options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Now because this is a singleton service and shared accross all pages. when i logout and login it's still using previous user data.
Is there any way to dispose this service in logout method.

Comment: did you update the data in login method?

Comment: @Duannx:Yes i did,it's updating app constants with new data.but it's not creating a new instance of that service. so it's still using previous user data.

Comment: Please post your singleton patterm and your login method when you updating the data.